# Datebox Returning strange timezone offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, datebox

On a subset of devices (this has been replicated) of which I can find no pattern fetching the time from the datebox is returning a 32 minute and 11 second timezone offset.

Sample code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("timeIn").datebox('open');
        var test = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        var date = new Date();

    $("#timeIn").datebox('setTheDate', "07:00 PM");
    $("#hello").text(new Date($("#timeIn").datebox('getTheDate').toString()));
    });
</script>

<html>
    <div id="hello">
    </div>
    <input name="timeBox" class="form-control" id="timeIn" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useFocus": true, "useButton": false }' __swhandlertypes="remove,focus,blur,change,datebox" readonly="readonly">
</html>
```

here is an example of the output on a device having the issue:

[Device with Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAxNj.png)

[Working device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjruo.png)

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! By default timebox returns January 1 1900 + the time. For some reason which I still haven't identified, when the year is 1900 on certain devices, it messes with the timezone offset. Appending the time to a date object with the year 2018 has fixed the issue.

Any insight to WHY this behavior occurs would be appreciated :).